# StackOverflowError when logging in a User that is supposed to see specific nodes in the Backoffice explorer tree

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris: 1905.9

I'm trying to create a UserGroup that is able to see specific nodes in the explorer tree. However, when I login the user, I get a StackOverflowError.

I've used these 2 sites as references:

- [Restricting access to the Hybris Commerce Backoffice application](https://www.acorel.nl/2017/04/restricting-access-to-the-hybris-commerce-backoffice-application/)
- [2455449 - How-to: Hide Backoffice explorer-tree nodes based on user access rights](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002455449)

What is wrong with the code?

**Impex:**

```
INSERT_UPDATE BackofficeRole;UID[unique = true];groups(uid)[mode = append];locName;name;backOfficeLoginDisabled;authorities
;custombackofficeadminrole;;Custom Backoffice Admin Role;Custom Backoffice Admin Role;false;custombackofficeadmin

INSERT_UPDATE UserGroup;uid[unique=true];groups(uid)
;custombackofficeadmingroup;

INSERT_UPDATE PrincipalGroupRelation;source(uid)[unique=true];target(uid)[unique=true]
;custombackofficeadmingroup;custombackofficeadminrole

$defaultPassword=1234

INSERT_UPDATE Employee;UID[unique=true];password[default=$defaultPassword];name;groups(uid)[mode=append]
;custombackofficeadmin;;custombackofficeadmin;custombackofficeadmingroup,employeegroup
```

**custombackoffice-backoffice-config.xml:**

```
<context merge-mode="none" component="explorer-tree" principal="custombackofficeadminrole" >
    <explorer-tree:explorer-tree xmlns:explorer-tree="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/explorertree">
        <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="hmc_treenode_custombackofficeadmin">
           <explorer-tree:navigation-node id="hmc_treenode_subnode">
                <explorer-tree:type-node id="hmc_typenode_product" code="Product"/>
                <explorer-tree:type-node id="hmc_typenode_category" code="Category"/>
           </explorer-tree:navigation-node>
        </explorer-tree:navigation-node>
    </explorer-tree:explorer-tree>
</context>
```

**Error:**

> INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:02.519 |
>   0407_22:16:02,416 INFO  [hybrisHTTP33] 
>   [com.hybris.cockpitng.composer.LoginFormComposer.initLangPacks:164]
>   Available UI locales for backoffice: [de, en, es, es_CO, fr, it, ja,
>   ko, pt, ru, zh, zh_TW, hi, id, cs, pl, hu] INFO   | jvm 1    | main
>   | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 | Apr 07, 2020 10:16:06 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke INFO   | jvm 1
>   | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 | SEVERE: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [zkLoader] in context with path [/backoffice] threw exception
>   [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause INFO   | jvm 1 
>   | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 | java.lang.StackOverflowError
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 |   at
>   net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1734) INFO   | jvm 1    | main
>   | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion.getWithLoader(EHCacheRegion.java:307)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.regioncache.DefaultCacheController.getWithLoader(DefaultCacheController.java:235)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getOrAddUnit(RegionCacheAdapter.java:213)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.tx.Transaction$GlobalCacheAdapter.getOrAddUnit(Transaction.java:2348)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit.get(AbstractCacheUnit.java:174)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloItemCacheUnit.getCached(JaloItemCacheUnit.java:113)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.core.WrapperFactory.getCachedItem(WrapperFactory.java:378)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.300 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item.isAlive(Item.java:3815) INFO   | jvm 1
>   | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |     at
>   de.hybris.platform.jalo.SessionContext.removeInvalidJaloItems(SessionContext.java:477)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.jalo.SessionContext.fixStaleItemsInValue(SessionContext.java:469)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.jalo.SessionContext.getAttribute(SessionContext.java:454)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloSession.getAttribute(JaloSession.java:1483)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.impl.DefaultSession.getAttribute(DefaultSession.java:59)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.impl.DefaultSessionService.getAttribute(DefaultSessionService.java:179)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.user.impl.DefaultUserService.getCurrentUser(DefaultUserService.java:129)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.user.BackofficeCockpitUserService.getCurrentUser(BackofficeCockpitUserService.java:43)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultAuthorityGroupContextStrategy.getParentContexts(DefaultAuthorityGroupContextStrategy.java:69)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4747)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4755)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.getParentValues(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:959)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.301 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.lambda$getParentValues$23(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:969)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.getParentValues(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:975)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.lambda$getParentValues$23(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:969)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.307 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.308 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.getParentValues(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:975)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.lambda$getParentValues$23(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:969)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.341 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.getParentValues(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:975)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.lambda$getParentValues$23(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:969)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.getParentValues(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:975)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.lambda$getParentValues$23(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:969)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.getParentValues(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:975)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.342 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.lambda$getParentValues$23(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:969)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.getParentValues(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:975)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.lambda$getParentValues$23(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:969)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.getParentValues(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:975)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.lambda$getParentValues$23(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:969)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.343 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.getParentValues(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:975)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   com.hybris.cockpitng.core.config.impl.DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.lambda$getParentValues$23(DefaultCockpitConfigurationService.java:969)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/04/07 22:16:06.344 |   at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, I think I found the cause. I can't have an Employee UID that is also the same as `Backoffice.authorities`.

I changed the value of the `authorities` from `custombackofficeadmin` to `custombackofficeadminrole`, and the StackOverflowError does not happen anymore.

```
INSERT_UPDATE BackofficeRole;UID[unique = true];groups(uid)[mode = append];locName;name;backOfficeLoginDisabled;authorities
;custombackofficeadminrole;;Custom Backoffice Admin Role;Custom Backoffice Admin Role;false;custombackofficeadminrole
```